AsyncRequestNotUsableException: Response not usable after async request completion
I am trying to implement a streaming ReST endpoint in my controller:
@GetMapping("/stream")
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamData() {
   Stream<Data> data = service.streamData();

   StreamingResponseBody responseBody = httpResponseOutputStream -> {
            try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(httpResponseOutputStream))) {
                data.forEach(d -> {
                    try {
                        writer.write(gson.toJson(d));
                        writer.flush();
                    } catch (IOException exception) {
                        logger.error("exception occurred while writing object to stream", exception);
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                logger.error("exception occurred while publishing data", exception);
            }
            logger.info("finished streaming records");
        };

   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(responseBody);
}

Service:
public Stream<Data> streamData() {
        jdbcTemplate.setFetchSize(500);
        String q = "SELECT .....";
        return this.jdbcTemplate.queryForStream(q,
                (resultSet, rowNum) -> {
                    Data d = transform(resultSet);

                    return d;
                }
        );
    }

All seems to be work fine for some time, but after some time of streaming the data, error shows up on server side as:
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: Response not usable after async request completion.

On client side I see error as:
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8080/stream": Premature EOF

I am not able to find out root cause.
Any input on this would be helpful.

In 3.3 I have this one org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to write: reset] when quickly close a browser in the middle of it.
